# I need to remove everything inside the parentheses without import re

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.8, parentheses

I need to remove parentheses and everything inside them

I wrote a code

```
def remove_parentheses(s):
    c = list(s)
    s1 = c.index('(')
    while ")" in c:
        c.pop(s1)
    c = "".join(c)
    c.strip(' ')
    return c
```

but it failed the last test

```
        test.assert_equals(remove_parentheses("(first group) (second group) (third group)"), "  ")
```

with an error

```
'' should equal '  '
```

How can i fix this? I can't use "import re" in my case.

Comment: `while ")" in c` means that your function will continue removing characters as long as there is *any* `)` left in the list. You need to refactor it so it only `pop`s up to the next `)`.

Comment: You also need to change the logic so that it handles disconnected parentheses, such as "word1 (first group) word2 (second group) word3".  Very simply, you haven't considered the full problem yet.  You have to **research how to match parentheses**, and then write code to handle your actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would construct a new list from the string and keep track of the current number of opening and closing brackets while iterating the string.

```
def remove_parentheses(text):
    data = []
    counter = 0
    for c in text:
        if c == '(':
            counter += 1
        if counter == 0:
            data.append(c)
        if c == ')':
            counter -= 1
    return ''.join(data)
```

If we find a `'('` we increase the counter. If we find a `')'` we decrease the counter. Characters are only added to the list if the counter is `0`.

The code needs some additional checks if you can have strings like `'a(b))c)(d(e(f)g'`. In that case the comparison might be `if counter <= 0:` (depending on your needs).